# vbox, twocolumn - how to prevent padding

Tags: two-column

If I have a twocolumn layout in an article, and there are parts that I do not want split so I
vbox them, this causes a lot of space to be inserted so the columns are even :

[image]

Is there a way to make thetwocolumn option behave as if you used \raggedcolumns in the multicol environment?

Comment: If I was using multicol, \raggedcolums would do it, as that allows unequal columns. I want to do something similar in the two-column option in an article class.

Comment: `\raggedbottom` in that case